# Finite groups as subgroups of dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

It is well-known that any finite group can be realised as a subgroup of a permutation group. But is it true that any finite group can be realised as a subgroup of a *dihedral* group?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, because every dihedral group $D_n$ is solvable, and hence every subgroup of $D_n$ is solvable, too.

Actually, more can be said. Every subgroup of $D_n$ is either cyclic or dihedral, see Theorem $3.1$ of K. Conrad's [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf). Therefore, say, $Q_8$ cannot be embedded (which we see by Doeke's answer).

Comment: Actually I got stuck in a problem of topology where I need some idea aboubt group theory, So if you don't mind, can you tell me is that fact correct or not if I replace dihedral group by the group of symmetries of a regular polytope?

Comment: If you don't mind can I edit this question with the last comment?

Comment: I've posted this as a separate qes here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920723/any-finite-group-can-be-realized-as-a-subgroup-of-the-group-of-symmetries-of-a-r

Answer (score 12):

No. Dietrich Burde's reason is quite nice, but there are easy elementary concrete counterexamples. Here's one:

$Q_8 = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ has six elements of order $4$, but no dihedral group has this property: all reflections in a dihedral group have order 2, and the only rotations of order $4$ are rotations by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ so a dihedral group has *at most* two elements of order $4$.

Comment: This is a nice observation. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I got stuck in a problem of topology where I need some idea aboubt group theory, So if you don't mind, can you tell me is that fact correct or not if I replace dihedral group by the group of symmetries of a regular polytope?

Comment: I've posted it as a separate qes here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920723/any-finite-group-can-be-realized-as-a-subgroup-of-the-group-of-symmetries-of-a-r

Comment: Also of order eight, but abelian, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ can be seen to be a counterexample.